# tar -czvf with no output file

Tags: bash, unix, tar

Say you run `tar -czvf some_folder_here` and don't actually specify an output file, like `tar -czvf some_output_file.tar some_folder_here`.

Where does the file go?

I just ran this by accident, and the `-v` option made it clear that it did SOMETHING, but I'm not sure where it actually went (if it went anywhere at all).

Comment: Many years ago I learned that a non GNU tar without option `f` is trying to access a tape drive. GNU tar writes to STDOUT without `f`.

Comment: Which version of `tar` are you using? the `tar` _(GNU tar) 1.27.1_ do not create any file for example

Comment: I tried to replicate it but in Ubuntu and I get a "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive" error.

Comment: Solaris 11 says (`tar czvf foo`): "Missing filenames" and without option `f` it says: "/dev/rmt/0: No such device or address".

Answer (score 0):

With the way `tar` or any standard Unix command-line tool would parse that command line, you specified an output filename (the first thing after the `f` option) , it just happened to be the same name as some folder. You failed to specify any files to ingest.

Most flavors of `tar` would have done nothing, either because you didn't specify any files to ingest, or because Unix filesystem API semantics don't let your clobber a directory with a file (IIRC).